# File Size to store an integer

Tags: c++, string, file, integer

I want to write an integer (for ex - 222222) to a text file in a way that the size of the file is reduced. If I write the integer in the form of a string, it takes 6 Bytes because of the six characters present. If I store the integer in the form of an integer, it again takes 6 Bytes. Why isn't the file size equal to 4 Bytes since an int takes 4 Bytes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //char* x = "222222.2222";
    //double x = 222222.2222;
    int x = 222222;
    FILE *fp = fopen("now.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp,"%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Try opening the file in an editor and see what was stored.

Comment: I opened the now.txt file in Notepad++ . It shows "222222".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the definition of [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/):

```
writes the C string pointed by format to the stream.
```

So whatever you pass to the function, they are treated as a `string`, that's the output file all has `222222` stored in it.

If you want to store a `integer` rather than a `string` in the file, you could use: `fwrite`.

```
int x = 222222;
FILE *fp = fopen("now.txt","w");
fwrite(&x, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

Then the file stores: `0E 64 03 00` if you change you editor to hex mode. It's **4** bytes.

Comment: If I want to further compress the number, what other techniques should I use. Will converting the number to any other base help?

Comment: @Hellboy, I don't think you could compress a single number anymore. But there is a workaround for plenty of data: you could write the data first and then compress them using some libraries, e.g., zip. Let the profession libraries do the job might be the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple reason behind this.

Whenever we write to file it's stored in characters. So when you write integer 222222 into a file it's written character by character not as an integer.

Comment: @Muhammad So, what can I do to reduce the amount of memory I need to store that integer in a file?

Comment: I don't know if you can reduce size further. Try storing in binary, this may or may not reduce the size

Comment: @Hellboy, take a look at the answer, `fwrite` would reduce the size.

Comment: Storing in binary doesn't reduce the size. But using fwrite() reduced the size to 4 Bytes.

Answer (score 0):

when you write integer as integer, that file turns in to a binary file.

When you write and read binary files, it's required to take care of the [paddings](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=padding+binary+file&oq=padding+binary&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3925j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) , [byte order](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=byte+order+binary+file&oq=byte+order+binary&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.6375j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) etc.
The other way around is plain text and you read it as strings and with the help of libraries we convert it to integers.